# Add same Observer multiple times to LiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata, observer-pattern, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

Our team is using `ViewModel` and `LiveData` components in developing the current Application. In one of the scenarios on a `Button` click, we are initiating a network API call.

The `Repository` returns a `LiveData` whenever the API results are available.

In the `ViewModel` we attach the `Observer` only when the `Button` is clicked and since we are in `ViewModel` we are using `observeForever()`

This is the code;

```kotlin
//ViewModel Code


//Api Observer
 var apiObserver: Observer<ApiState> =
            Observer { response ->

                when (response.currentState) {

                    StateConstants.STATE_API_CALLED -> showLoading()
                    StateConstants.STATE_API_COMPLETE -> stopLoading()
                    StateConstants.STATE_DATA_LOADED -> processResponseData(response.data)
                    StateConstants.STATE_API_ERROR -> showError(response.errorMessage)

                }
            }


fun sendReminderToCustomer() { //This method is called on Button click from XML

        repo.apiStateLiveData.observeForever(apiObserver) //attach Observer and Observe Forever
        repo.sendReminderDetails() //make api call 

    }

override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        repo.apiStateLiveData.removeObserver(apiObserver) //remove Observer
    }
```

Since on every button click, we are attaching the same observer to the `LiveData` will there be any unknown side effects like,

1. Will the same observer get added to `LiveData` observer list multiple times?
2. If the same observer is added multiple times will the `onChanged()` method get called multiple times too?

Comment: take a look at this topic, maybe it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107330/is-observeforever-lifecycle-aware

Comment: Pretty much every time I had idea to "observeForever" in view model it turned out to be bad idea that had to be refactored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and yes. Be sure to add an observer only once (in your viewModel's `init`, for example)